# Webview from Android Studio does show a navigation menu and background logo

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

**Context**
I'm trying to implement a webview for my website, using Android Studio and Java. Here is the code for

- MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.neurofinance;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(

                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE

                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);//setting wide view
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//setting default zoomed out view
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//setting zoom controls

        webView.loadUrl("www.URL.com");
        

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());

                return true;

            }

        };

        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);


    }
}
```

- AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.neurofinance">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

- activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Problem**
My webview does not show the navigation menu (dots) and the banner. The following two screenshots show my webview (left) and the website itself (right).

[image]

The solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360233/website-menu-bar-not-working-with-webview-android-while-working-fine-in-mobile-b) did not help.
Namely, I tried these:

```java
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone suggest to me what I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site is https. Webview does not allow resources that are http to be uploaded.
There are several ways to solve this problem:

1- Change Http Files To Https In Your Site.
For example, for your site, the image source in the post-14.css file:

[http://neurofinance.rf.gd/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/бэк-1.png](http://neurofinance.rf.gd/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA-1.png)
To
[https://neurofinance.rf.gd/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/бэк-1.png](https://neurofinance.rf.gd/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA-1.png)

and ....

2-
A-If you're targeting API level 26 or above, you must first enable it in the manifest file. Add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

into `<application>` tag.

B-Use the following command for WebView:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) 
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE );
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried only the second step and it worked!

Comment: The second step is to prevent any other http file on the site from getting errors and opening them.
If you want to open only https resources and URLs, use the first step

Comment: Edit : please use  WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE instead WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW  .this is better